# How to use şŞıİçÇöÖüÜĞğ characters in a regular expression in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, regex, character-encoding

I tried using a regular expression to capture names:

```
r[1].scan(/^([A-Z]|[ŞİÇÖÜĞ])([a-z]|[şŞıİçÇöÖüÜĞğ])*\s([A-Z]|[ŞİÇÖÜĞ])([a-z]|[şŞıİçÇöÖüÜĞğ])*/u)
```

But, it gives me an error:

```
syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting ')'
...atches = r[1].scan(/^([A-Z]|[ŞİÇÖÜĞ])([a-z]|[şŞ�...
...
```

I see that the problem is the Turkish characters I'm using. Is it possible to use unicode values of the characters in regexp? How can I use these problematic characters in this regexp?

Comment: It could be just an encoding problem in your file, because I can use those characters just fine.

Comment: Although while I've got you, `([A-Z]|[ŞİÇÖÜĞ])` could be rewritten as `([A-ZŞİÇÖÜĞ])`. You could also get rid of the parens here if you aren't capturing anything there. Also, have you considered using [unicode character properties](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html) (eg: `\p{L}`) instead of listing everything out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use ruby 1.9
2. Go with `/\p{Word}+\p{Space}\p{Word}*/`